# imagemagick - animate, with a static black background?

Tags: imagemagick

Just a quickie.

I have a series of images `min*.png` that I want to animate into a gif.

They are each fully transparent, **except** for some white dots on the area I want filled in for that frame.

Is there some way to create an animation from these such that the background is black (so that the whtie dots show up?)

I am interested in both:

1. black background, and paste each successive image on top of the previous ones (so frame `i` is the black background plus all of the dots up to image `i`)
2. each frame consists of just (image i on a black background)

I think for 1. I need to use `-dispose none` and for 2 I use `-dispose background` or `-dispose previous`, but various attempts at actually setting the background to black have failed (I have spent a lot of time reading [this imagemagick page](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_basics/#background) but am still learning).

e.g.

```
convert -background black -dispose background min*.png out.gif
```

various attempts with `-background` and `-dispose` have invariably produced a gif of my `min*.png` with a transparent background, not a black one. I think I'm close, but not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be useful for the black background problem: starting from ImageMagick 6.7.5 you can remove transparency and replace it with a static color; you can read more about this command [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/masking/#alpha_remove)

Hope this helps, unfortunately I have an older version of Imagemagick, so i can't try it myself

Example from ImageMagick documentation:

```
  convert moon.png  -background tan  -alpha remove  alpha_remove.png
```

The color "tan" replaces the transparent areas of the picture

---

Comment from mathematical.coffee

Using the above answer, I was able to generate the animations I wanted.

1: successive buildup of dots, all on a black background. Turned out to be as simple as creating a black background picture to put at the start of the animation, and using `-coalesce`:

```
# where bg.png is a black png of the appropriate size:
convert bg.png min*.png -coalesce out.gif
# in the below the first line creates the black background
#  image, same size as my first min00.png image, for me:
convert min00.png -alpha Opaque +level-colors black \
    min*.png -coalesce out.gif
```

2. use the method mentioned above:

```
convert min000*.png -background black -alpha remove out.gif
```

In both I was using imagemagick 6.7.something.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - looks like it could work for my second point, though unsure about my first. Unfortunately I'm on imagemagick 6.7.0 at the moment so will have to find a newer version somewhere!

Comment: OK, I've given this a go with a newer version of imagemagick, and it certainly works for part 2) in my question (each frame has the black background put on and then it is composed into an animation). Do you know how to achieve 1) ? (overlay each image successively so that the dots build up over time, and put a black background on afterwards?)

Comment: OK worked out number 1): will edit your answer with that and accept.